# Distributing a purchase quantity into rated bands

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am working on a monthly billing application that utilises a rate band pricing mechanism to reward increasing consumption within a designated billing period. For example:

Say I have the following rates bands:

```
Minimum Quantity | Price
---------------------------
     10              1
     20             0.5
     50             0.2
```

Which equates to customers paying the following prices:

```
     CustomerId   |   Quantity Purchased | Cost
   ------------------------------------------------
           1                 10             10
           2                 20             15
           3                 50             21
           4                100             31
```

I have coded an a working example to calculate the above costs, but for some reason it feels like a sledgehammer to crack a walnut and I'm wondering if there is a name for type of problem/solution and whether anyone can enlighten me as to what it is and whether there is a more elegant solution?

My working solution is:

```
 // Example Usage

public class Main
{
    public void Run()
    {
        var usageCostCalculator = new UsageCostCalculator();
        var rates = new[] {
            new Rate { Price = 1, MinimumQuantity = 10 } ,
            new Rate { Price = 0.5m, MinimumQuantity = 20 } ,
            new Rate { Price = 0.2m, MinimumQuantity = 50 }
        };

        var orderCost = usageCostCalculator.CalculateOrderCost(10, rates, 0);
    }

}

// Implementation 

public class UsageCostCalculator
{

    public decimal CalculateOrderCost(double quantity, IEnumerable<Rate> rates, double previouslyPurchase)
    {
        var rateBandSet = new RateBandSet(rates);

        rateBandSet.Distribute(previouslyPurchase);
        rateBandSet.Adjust();
        rateBandSet.Distribute(quantity);

        return rateBandSet.TotalAllocatedPrice;
    }


    private class Band
    {
        public double AllowQuantity;
        public double AllocatedAmount;
        public decimal Price;
        public int RateId;
    }

    private class RateBandSet
    {
        private List<Band> bands;
        public IEnumerable<Band> Bands { get { return bands; } }

        public RateBandSet(IEnumerable<Rate> rates)
        {
            bands = new List<Band>();

            for (int i = 0; i < rates.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    var rate = rates.ElementAt(i);
                    bands.Add(new Band { RateId = rate.Id, AllowQuantity = rate.MinimumQuantity, Price = rate.Price });
                }
                else
                {
                    var previousRate = rates.ElementAt(i - 1);
                    var rate = rates.ElementAt(i);
                    bands.Add(new Band { RateId = rate.Id, AllowQuantity = rate.MinimumQuantity - previousRate.MinimumQuantity, Price = rate.Price });
                }
            }

            // Last band should be bottomless.
            var orderedBuckets = bands.OrderBy(x => x.AllowQuantity);
            orderedBuckets.Last().AllowQuantity = double.MaxValue;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Band> AllocatedBands
        {
            get
            {
                return bands.Where(x => x.AllocatedAmount > 0);
            }
        }

        public decimal TotalAllocatedPrice
        {
            get
            {
                return AllocatedBands.Select(x => (decimal)x.AllocatedAmount * x.Price).Sum();
            }
        }

        private void Allocate(double quantity)
        {
            var bucket = bands.OrderBy(x => x.AllowQuantity).Where(x => x.AllowQuantity - x.AllocatedAmount > 0).First();
            bucket.AllocatedAmount += quantity;
        }

        public void Distribute(double quantity)
        {
            int integerQuantity = (int)quantity;
            double fractionalQuantity = quantity - integerQuantity;

            for (int i = 0; i < integerQuantity; i++)
            {
                Allocate(1);
            }

            Allocate(fractionalQuantity);
        }

        public void Adjust()
        {
            bands = bands.Select(x => new Band { RateId = x.RateId, AllowQuantity = (x.AllowQuantity - x.AllocatedAmount), Price = x.Price }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! As a courtesy to other users, you should either mention your [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37305629/1157100) or just delete your Stack Overflow question.

Comment: You should include the definition for `Rate` class, so we didn't have to guess it, which wasn;t hard.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is nicely organized, but there really isn't much to the calculation that it would require all of that.  All you really need is your `Rate` enumeration and a variable of how much you've accounted for so far.

This code simply loops over the rates and starts summing by bracket until the quantity is fulfilled or it runs out of rates.  Any remaining quantity is added in at the highest rate.

```
public decimal CalculateOrderCost(double quantity, IEnumerable<Rate> rates, double previouslyPurchase)
{
    decimal totalCost = 0;
    double purchasedSoFar = previouslyPurchase;  // or set to zero
    foreach(Rate rate in rates)
    {
        if(quantity > rate.MinimumQuantity)
        {
            totalCost += (rate.MinimumQuantity - purchasedSoFar) * rate.Price;
            purchsedSoFar += (rate.MinimumQuantity - purchasedSoFar);
        }
        else
        {
            totalCost += (rate.MinimumQuantity - purchasedSoFar) * rate.Price;
            return totalCost;
        }
    }

    //account for anything remaining by using the last price bracket 
    if(purchasedSoFar != quantity)
    {
        totalCost += (quantity - purchasedSoFar) * rates[rates.length-1].rate;
    }
    return totalCost;
}
```

(Note that I wrote and tested this code in ruby and then ported it to C# by hand, so there may be a minor issue when multiplying decimals and floats or other trivial compilation errors)